# How can I tell if my google DFP is already linked with my Adsense?

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

A former co-worker signed up for an Adsense and Google DFP account. They have since left and I'm trying to figure out if they already linked the DFP account to the Adsense account. I have already read a number of articles, including this one:

https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/188529?hl=en

However, the instructions do not match what I see. I do not see anything called "3rd party services" under Admin in DFP.

Does anyone know how I can check the the DFP and Adsense accounts are now linked?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work if you're using DFP for Small Business. instead, you'll just want to add your Adsense embed code as a third-party creative.

Comment: sorry can you elaborate a bit more? Why doesn't it work for DFP small business? I am using DFP for Small Business. So if I want to add Adsense I have to ad it as a third-party creative? Is that right? I tried following the instructions, but the "third party creative" isn't listed anywhere!